# HP Agile Manager versus JIRA

Tags: test-management, agile, hp-quality-center, jira, scrum

Has anyone used and able to offer a comparison of HP Agile Manager versus JIRA in a scrum environment, with 2 week sprints? This is considering test management, the benefits of integrated bug tracking, product backlog management, and traceability, and reporting & metrics.

I was thinking not only how the features compare (including any add-ons used with JIRA), but a comparison of benefits delivered by any features, value of workflows encouraged, ease of use/learning curve...and whether one turned out to have a better ROI in the long run?

Any info is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this hasn't been answered or commented on for months I figure I will answer.  No I haven't used HP Agile Manager, but I have utilized and administered Jira and other atlassian tools for several years and would recommend that hands down for any ticket/bug/wiki/process tool.  Jira is highly customizable (newer versions) and has tons of benefits for various project separation including screens/workflows/issue types/security/user grouping and more.

I have executed agile and CMMI 5 processes and bugs successfully and efficiently utilizing Jira and tied into confluence for wiki support that also contained use cases and design docs that were linked to requirements in Jira and bugs and related to functionality rolled up that then offered good graphs and output tracking that satisfied every level of management including external auditors.

Out of the box Jira has a basic flow that can easily be used for agile scrum like processes and has a an Agile package for management, bonfire for test execution/screenshot to bug generation, GIT and SVN integration is available as well.  The code is open source(https://www.atlassian.com/opensource/overview#!) although usage is licensed so that you can pay for licensing and develop anything you want in java to tie into Jira.